# Google Map Over Query Limit

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a problem when i try to geocode something. I have this script :

```
$geo =     file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false');
$geo = json_decode($geo, true);

if ($geo['status'] = 'OK' ) {
  $Lat = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
  $Long = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
} else {
 $Lat = 46;
 $Long = 2;
 $message="error";
}
```

At first , it worked like a charm but now ( i geocode like 1 or two adresses per day), i got the alert "OVER QUERY LIMIT" every time.

Any suggestions ? I don't really think that i can reach the Google map limit with one or two query per day , am i right ?

Comment: nothing like reading the fine print : only you know whether your actual usage (server + front-end) corresponds to **[the method for calculating quota usage](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_quotacalc)** documented by google for usage of its 'freeish' service.

Comment: Actually , its the only script i use for geocoding and it was like once per day . I already read this page  but i don't understand how i can reach their limit . Is the "key" parameter necessary ?

Comment: Keys are now required for all of google's services.  Some domains _may_ be grandfathered with keyless access, but you _should_ now always include a key.